# Froala code snippet losing breaklines on edit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, froala, pre

I am making a simple blog in RoR.
When I edit a post I am losing all linebreakes in the code snippet.
How can I make sure that when I am reloading the content of the post, the editor correctly formats the code snippets?

This is the input into the text editor:

`A 
 B`

This is the source code in the froala editor generated using a custom button:

`<pre><code>A
 B</code></pre>`

This is the data inserted into the database:

`"<pre><code>A\r\nB</code></pre>"`

This is how it looks like on the web page:

[image]

This is how it looks like in the Froala editor when I try to update the post:

[image]

This is how the source code looks like this time:

`<pre><code>AB</code></pre>`

This is the code for the custom button:

```
customButtons: {
insertCode: {
title: 'Insert code',
  icon: {
    type: 'font',
      value: 'fa fa-code'
  },
    callback: function() {
      if (!this.selectionInEditor()) {
        this.$element.focus(); // Focus on editor if it's not.
      }

      var html = '<pre><code>' + (this.text() || '&#8203;') + '<span class="f-marker" data-type="false" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span><span class="f-marker" data-type="true" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span></code></pre>';

      this.insertHTML(html);
      this.restoreSelectionByMarkers();
      this.saveUndoStep();
    }
  }
}
```

-------------------------Update-----------------------------

The problem seems to be with the froala initiation function:

step 1:
create a textarea with the content:

```
<textarea id="froalaedit" name="content">
<pre><code>A
B</code></pre>
</textarea>
```

step 2:
add a button to initiate the froala editor:

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
  $('textarea#froalaedit').editable({
    inlineMode: false,
    buttons: ['html', 'removeFormat', 'sep', 'undo', 'redo', 'sep', 'insertHorizontalRule', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'sep', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'sep', 'formatBlock', 'blockStyle', 'align', 'sep', 'insertOrderedList', 'insertUnorderedList', 'sep', 'createLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'table', 'uploadFile', 'fullscreen', 'insertCode'],
    minHeight: 200,
    customButtons: {
      insertCode: {
        title: 'Insert code',
        icon: {
          type: 'font',
          value: 'fa fa-code'
        },
        callback: function() {
          if (!this.selectionInEditor()) {
            this.$element.focus(); // Focus on editor if it's not.
          }

          var html = '<pre><code>' + (this.text() || '&#8203;') + '<span class="f-marker" data-type="false" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span><span class="f-marker" data-type="true" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span></code></pre>';

          this.insertHTML(html);
          this.restoreSelectionByMarkers();
          this.saveUndoStep();
        }
      }
    }
  })
};
</script>
```

Step 3: The behaviour is replicated when the button is pressed.

--------------------Fixed------------------------

did this:

```
<div id="eg-textarea"><%= @post.content.html_safe %></div>
```

instead of this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 40, id: 'eg-textarea' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with `\n` inside `textarea` and it was not rendered properly. You can either use a `div` instead of textarea or use the [master version](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/commit/842da7c8a1ebb5407c45fb001ecbd02d4d971bec) from Github which fixes the issue.